# What is grub and how can I use it

Tags: linux

I would like to know how to use grub and what it is used for. I would also like to know if I can boot freebsd and linux with grub. I have googled it but couldn't find much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

grub is a bootloader that allows you to boot multiple distros and or kernels. Your motherboard should allow you to boot multiple partitions.